# How to read from firestore and manage case data is missing in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello I think I am getting lost in a glass of water. I would like to read data from firestore and I managed to do so by using the following

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('talks')
    .where("topic", isEqualTo: "flutter")
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) =>
        data.documents.forEach((doc) => print(doc["title"])));
```

It is all good and if there is data then I can print all the relevant titles. 
Let assume the database does not include documents with a “flutter” topic. I would like to print “no document exist”. How can I do it???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Check Whether the topic exists or not !

```
//This Query will Check If The Topic Already Exists || !
Future<bool> doesTopicAlreadyExist(String topic) async {
  debugPrint('inquery');
  final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('talks')
      .where('topic', isEqualTo: topic)
      .limit(1)
      .getDocuments();
  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
  debugPrint('donequery');
  print(documents.length == 1);//printing whether it exists or not!
  return documents.length == 1; //This returns a bool whether the value exists or not !
}
```

And Handle It Later Like This If Topic Does Not Exists...

```
doesTopicAlreadyExist("topic").then((val){ val == false ? Handle() : Handle()});
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure what the Handle methods is actually doing... Can you please integrate your code with an IF logic to either print the title or print "no docs exists" if the topic does not exist??

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I eventually wrote and it is working.
Thanks to Bhupendra

```
Future doesTopicAlreadyExist(String topic) async {
    debugPrint('inquery');
    final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('books')
        .where('topic', isEqualTo: topic)
        .where("restaurantId", isEqualTo: appData.restaurantId)
        .limit(1)
        .getDocuments();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
    if (documents.length == 1) {
      print(documents[0]['points']);
      setState(() {
        balance = documents[0]['title'].toString();
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        balance = balance = 'No title exists !';
      });
    }
    print(documents.length == 1); //printing whether it exists or not!
  }
```